# Newton Cotes Rule Derivation

Tags: integration, computational-mathematics

I have this question
Derive an open two-point Newton-Cotes quadrature rule for the interval $[a,b]$.

I need to find what the resulting weights and nodes are. What is the degree of the resulting rule?

Here is my work so far:
I know that for data points that are open,
$$ x_i = a + i\cdot\frac{b-a}{n+1} $$

so i have $x_1 = a + \frac{b-a}{2}$
and $x_2 = a + 2\frac{b-a}{3}$

how do i find the weights, nodes and degrees?

i think for the weights i have $$ \int_{a}^{b} 1 dx $$
and 
$$ \int_{a}^{b} x dx $$

but i do not know how to solve for them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your points are $x_1=a+1\cdot\frac{b-a}3=\frac{2a+b}3$ and $x_2=a+2\cdot\frac{b-a}3=\frac{a+2b}3$

Now determine weights $w_1,w_2$ so that
$$
w_1f(x_1)+w_2f(x_2)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
$$
for $f(x)=1$ and $f(x)=x$, and if possible, also for $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: you have typo in third line. should be $w_2 f(x_2)$

Comment: Thanks @MikeySpivak.

Comment: question: For n ≥ 2, there can be more than one quadrature rule that have n nodes and have a degree 2n−1?

Comment: In principle yes, as the system is non-linear. But practically you get only the Gauss formulas as real solutions, if I remember right.

Comment: I just posted this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182440/deriva-parameters-of-gauss-quadrature-rule perhaps you know how to do it